# Animate item when it comes to viewport react native listview

Tags: listview, react-native

I am working with ListView in react-native and i want to animate items when its visible to user while scrolling. i searched on internet from many days and found few libraries, but i coudlnt implement it. If anyone has working example code, that would be helpful

i am looking for something like this link when list is scrolling (specific that part, not other than that)

[enter link description here](https://dribbble.com/shots/3452502-Layout-Mode-Switch)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pan Responder to handle gestures. For example, listening to moveY and animate the transition between your views

You can learn more about it in the official docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: i read the article but its not what i want to implement or i dont know how to use it in my example. If you have any example code, it would be appriciated

Comment: I have this simple example in my github using pan responder to make an image swiping. You can check if it helps https://github.com/soutot/react-native-study-swipe